# How would I get my code to let the user submit a breed of dog and return pictures of the specific breed

Tags: javascript, api

i've been teaching myself to code for 3 months so forgive me if my question is hard to understand. I added a search bar in my app (I think my html code for the search bar is correct but I would appreciated it someone took a look at it) and I was trying to find out how I can make my app load a single random image for a specific breed, based on a user input, and also make the app account for the happy case when the breed is found, as well as the unhappy case when it is not.

heres a link straight to it but the code can also be ran through this post.What do I need to add to my js?

`

```js
'use strict';

function getDogImage() {
  fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breed/hound/images/random')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => 
      displayResults(responseJson))
    .catch(error => alert('Something went wrong. Try again later.'));
}

function displayResults(responseJson) {
  console.log(responseJson);
  //replace the existing image with the new one
  $('.results-img').replaceWith(
    `<img src="${responseJson.message}" class="results-img">`
  )
  //display the results section
  $('.results').removeClass('hidden');
}

function watchForm() {
  $('form').submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    getDogImage();
  });
}

$(function() {
  console.log('App loaded! Waiting for submit!');
  watchForm();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Dog API Example</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Dog API: A Simple Example</h1>
           
        <form>
             <label for="breed">Breed</label>
      <input type="search" name="phone" id="breed" placeholder="Enter Breed" title="dog breeds"/>

          <input type="submit" value="Get a dog pic!">
        </form>
        <section class="results hidden">
          <h2>Look at this dog!</h2>
          <img class="results-img" alt="placeholder">
        </section>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`https://repl.it/@Mike65/get-fetch-dog-api-example-DOM-3

Comment: `pattern=""` ... won't allow you to enter anything

Comment: what else should I add to my js to make it work?

Comment: what's wrong with the JS? I mean you `fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breed/hound/images/random')` so, you're going to get a random picture no matter what you do in JS

Comment: I want my app to generate a random picture of a specific breed of dog the user searches for in the search box.

Comment: OK, so, does the API you use allow you to do that?

Comment: is there a change that has to be made in the api?

Comment: oh, right ... breed/hound .... so you need to change hound to the user input

Comment: how do I change the hound to a user input?

Comment: working code posted as answer

Answer (score 1):

So, what you need to do is

- read the entered breed from #breed element
- pass that to `getDogImage`
- accept an argument in `getDogImage` ...lets call it `breed`
- use this entered breed as the value after `breed` in the URL path ... e.g. `.../api/breed/dingo/images`

See following, tested and working, code

```js
'use strict';

function getDogImage(breed) {
  fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${breed}/images/random`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => 
      displayResults(responseJson))
    .catch(error => alert('Something went wrong. Try again later.'));
}

function displayResults(responseJson) {
  console.log(responseJson);
  //replace the existing image with the new one
  $('.results-img').replaceWith(
    `<img src="${responseJson.message}" class="results-img">`
  )
  //display the results section
  $('.results').removeClass('hidden');
}

function watchForm() {
  $('form').submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    getDogImage($('#breed').val());
  });
}

$(function() {
  console.log('App loaded! Waiting for submit!');
  watchForm();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Dog API Example</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Dog API: A Simple Example</h1>
           
        <form>
             <label for="breed">Breed</label>
      <input type="search" name="phone" id="breed" placeholder="Enter Breed" title="dog breeds"/>

          <input type="submit" value="Get a dog pic!">
        </form>
        <section class="results hidden">
          <h2>Look at this dog!</h2>
          <img class="results-img" alt="placeholder">
        </section>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```